# SQL AES Encryption - Query Failed Incorrect string value in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, aes

I am using AES_Encryption in SQL query using PHP on ZendServer.
CODE SAMPLE:

```
<?php 
 .
 .
 .
$ID = uniqid();
$key = "bac09c63f34c9845c707228b20cac5e0";
$lenght= rand(300, 400);
for ($x = 0; $x < $lenght; $x++) {
    $prob1.= rand(0, 9);
    $prob2.= rand(0, 9);
}

$query= "INSERT INTO Table1 (ID, prob1, prob2) 
         values ('$ID'
        , AES_ENCRYPT('$prob1','$key')
            , AES_ENCRYPT('$prob2','$key')
                    );";
.
.
.
?>
```

Again the code works fine in WAMP server and all is UTF8. So , how can I encode and decode this and to work ?

Comment: What is `'$ID'` and where is it it set?, if the column is auto-increment its not required and its most definitely **not** a string. please show the actual error message.

Comment: I edit a code. $ID is uniquid() and error is: Incorrect string value: '\xF3w i z...' for column 'prob1' at row 1. I will try to change Column type and I will come back.

Comment: It worked. I used column type BLOB so it works fin until I hit a limit  after that I got error: incorect string values... SO I change to LONGBLOB and it works. By the way, what is bigger than LONGBLOB ??